# supertest EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, supertest

This seems to be a common question on SO, but I've tried all of the suggestions and just can't seem to get past it.  The common solution seems to be a strategically placed:

```
process.setMaxListeners(0);
```

But I just can't seem to figure out where to put it.  Its happening in my test cases: https://github.com/socketwiz/swblog/blob/master/test/contact.js

It was fine at first but as I began adding more test cases it started producing the following error:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at process.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at process.on.process.addListener (node.js:769:26)
    at Object.module.exports [as shutdown] (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/lib/middleware/shutdown.js:41:13)
    at Object.proto._middleware (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/lib/appcore.js:166:24)
    at next (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/lib/appcore.js:77:18)
    at Object.configure (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/index.js:10:5)
    at Object.proto._configure (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/lib/appcore.js:85:28)
    at Object.proto.init (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/lib/appcore.js:35:14)
    at create (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/lib/appcore.js:258:13)
    at Promise.apply (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:26)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/q/q.js:1337:14
    at flush (/Users/socketwiz/Sites/swblog/node_modules/kraken-js/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

It doesn't seem to be any particular test because if I comment a test that is failing, it will just move to a different test.

In an attempt to fix it I've tried setting:

```
server.setMaxListeners(0);
```

here: https://github.com/socketwiz/swblog/blob/master/test/contact.js#L21

I also tried setting

```
server.setMaxListeners(0);
```

here: https://github.com/socketwiz/swblog/blob/master/index.js#L15

But I just don't seem to be having any luck.  Any ideas where I should put it, or is there a better solution?  I'm using node v0.10.26.  My entire project can be found here for reference: https://github.com/socketwiz/swblog

As best as I can tell everything is working and this is just a warning, but its kind of annoying :(

Comment: Any chance you resolved this?

Comment: No I did not, sorry :(

Comment: I see. I may have made a brute force workaround. Every time a test ends, I remove all listeners.

Comment: Check if you turn off Sentry in Test mode. More info here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69740670/6347244